# Keycloak login page doesn't show PWA install option or application manifest

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, progressive-web-apps

I've a react PWA application with a `manifest.json in public folder`. My app display the Home page 15 seconds for the user & automatically redirect to Keycloak login page if user is not logged.

All the pages I developed, PWA install option I can see in the browser. But when the user is in Keycloak pages this option is not visible. When I checked from `dev tools` I can see no application manifest is available for Keycloak pages.

I want PWA install option across all the pages for seamless user experience. How can I add install option for Keycloak pages?